# How to create a recursive folder menu using pystray?

Tags: python, pystray

I am trying to create a navigable tree of folders and subfolders using pystray. I am having trouble creating a recursive menu with pystray.

I am getting an error

```py
"TypeError: MenuItem.__init__() takes from 3 to 8 positional arguments but 1757 were given".
```

Yes my folder has 1757 .cfr files...

The code is attached below. How can I create a recursive menu using pystray where only the last .cfr file of each folder is clickable while the other files in the folder are only for navigation?

```py
import os

import pystray


class OpenTrees:
    def __init__(self, dir_path):
        self.dir_path = dir_path
        self.submenus = self._create_submenus()
        icon = pystray.Icon('name',
                            icon=pystray.Icon('icon.png', width=32, height=32))
        icon.menu = pystray.Menu(*self.submenus)
        icon.run()

    def _create_submenus(self, file_path=None):
        submenus = []
        file_path = file_path or self.dir_path
        for file in sorted(os.listdir(file_path)):
            full_file_path = os.path.join(file_path, file)

            if os.path.isdir(full_file_path):
                submenu = pystray.MenuItem(file, *self._create_submenus(
                    file_path=full_file_path))
                submenus.append(submenu)

            elif file.endswith('.cfr'):
                submenu = pystray.MenuItem(file, lambda: print('Hello'))
                submenus.append(submenu)

        return submenus


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OpenTrees(dir_path=r"D:\Trees\AllTrees")
```

Here is an visual example of what I would like as the final result, only the first .cfr item appears in the menu, and the folders are all navigable..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
...
            if os.path.isdir(full_file_path):
                submenu = pystray.MenuItem(file, *self._create_submenus(
                    file_path=full_file_path))
                submenus.append(submenu)
```

2nd argument in `pystray.MenuItem(file, *sequence, file_path=full_file_path)` actually gets unpacked and becomes N arguments instead, you likely need to change that call into

```
pystray.MenuItem(file, self._create_submenus(
                    file_path=full_file_path))
```

note the missing `*`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: hello, your solution keep only the first level of folders in the menu [see](https://i.imgur.com/ZaazL4d.png)

Comment: try limiting a number of items passed by doing `self._create_submenus(file_path=full_file_path)[:5]`